# asp.net C# sql query dependant on session data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, code-behind

I have a `Session`, which is list `int`, and I need to make a query that will take from a database only those rows that have the `PK` value that exists in `Session`.

I was thinking of doing it with the `IN` function, or making a new datatable with 1 collumn and values from the Session and doing a double join, probably left...

I just dont know how to make a table from a list.

What I have so far:

```
String ConnString = "Data Source=BRACO-PC\SQL1;Initial Catalog=DiplomskiSQL1SQL;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
Conn.Open();
DataTable ukosarici = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Proizvodi.ime, TipProizvoda.tip, Proizvodi.dimenzije, Proizvodi.cijena from Proizvod LEFT JOIN TipProizvoda On Proizvod.tip=TipProizvoda.id_t WHERE Proizvod.id_p IN ", Conn);
SqlCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(ukosarici);
GridView1.DataSource = ukosarici;
GridView1.DataBind();
Conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table or table variable, insert the ints into it using `INSERT` or `BULK INSERT`, do a join in the SQL query then drop the temp table or table variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this, but one of my preferred methods is to serialize the list to a CSV, e.g. '1,3,5,33'.  I then use a custom SQL Table function to de-serialize the list and filter in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t
JOIN dbo.ufn_CSVtoTextList('1,3,5,33' , ',') csv
ON csv.[Entry] = t.Id
```

The ufn_CSVtoTextList function `CREATE` script is below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CSVToTextlist] ( @StringInput nVARCHAR(max) ,@SepChar nchar(1) = ',')
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [Entry] nVarchar(255), [index] int identity (0,1) )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Entry   nVarChar(255)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Entry      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@SepChar, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@SepChar, @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [Entry] )
        VALUES ( @Entry )
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing your SqlDataAdapter Call as follows

```
 List<int> list ; // Assign with your session int list values
            List<string> l2 = list.ConvertAll<string>(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });
            string query = "Select Proizvodi.ime, TipProizvoda.tip, Proizvodi.dimenzije, Proizvodi.cijena from Proizvod LEFT JOIN TipProizvoda On Proizvod.tip=TipProizvoda.id_t WHERE Proizvod.id_p IN (";
            query = query + string.Join(",", l2.ToArray()) + ")";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Conn);
```